# C++, Variables reverting to initial values

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class, shapeObject, that is somewhat complicated but this question is only regarding two particular fields of the class, dX and dY.

```
header:
    class shapeObject{
        public:
            shapeObject();
                    ...

        private:
            float dX, dY;
                    ... 
    };

cpp file:
    shapeObject::shapeObject(){
            ...
            dX = 0;
            dY = 0;
            ...
    }
```

These fields are only modified by one function, which adds or subtracts a small float value to dX or dY. However, the next time the value of dX or dY is read, they have reverted back to their original value of 0.0 .

Since the fields are not being modified anywhere but that one function, and that function is never setting the values to 0.0, I'm not sure why they are reverting to the original value. Any ideas of why this could be happening?

Comment: Post your complete code, I'm sure it has a bug. Also, use the constructor-initializer.

Comment: buffer overflow, wild pointers, premature object deletion... can we see more code?

Comment: Also, how do you determine that the values are zero? Depending on your method of output, very small values can *appear* to be zero, when in fact they aren't.

Comment: Please distill your program to the smallest program that still displays your error, and then post that program. In the process, you may discover the bug on your own. For more information about how to create a minimal complete program, and why it is important, see http://sscce.org

Answer (score 9):

My psychic debugging skills indicate some possibilities:

- You're shadowing the members when you assign them `float dX = small_float_value;` instead of `dX = small_float_value;`
- You're working with different copies of `shapeObject` and the modified one gets thrown away by accident (or its copy constructor doesn't do the obvious thing).
- The values only *appear* to still be zero in printing but are in fact the small float value you want.
- Somehow the small float value gets truncated to zero.

Comment: You skills impress me padawan.

Comment: +1 But come on, concentrate a little harder and narrow it down to 1 instead of 4 :-)

Comment: Miss Cleo says you nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

When adding or subtracting a small value try using cast by float like dx=dx+(float)0.001;
Better try using double instead of float.Float has some precision problem.

Comment: Double has just as much a precision problem. Sure, you get a bit more accuracy, but you're still dealing with floating point math.

Comment: just for a smaller value double can be solution whereas float not

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somewhere the small float value is being cast to an int before being added/subtracted so the resulting change is zero?

Need to see more code to do anything more than stab in the dark.